# Path is denied, not able to run ps1 script

Tags: powershell

Trying to run the following, but getting a message path is denied
I am new to powershell

```
Set-Location -Path "C:\work\test

$newFILEStest=(1..100) 
foreach($f in $newFILEStest) 
{
$newFiletest1="business" +$f + ".txt" 
new-item $newfiletest1 -path $source_businesspath

} 

$source_businesspath = "C:\work\test\$(Get-Date -Format "yyyy-MM-dd")\business
```

Goal is: loop generate files  such as business.txt inside of the subfolder: business.
Be able to run the ps1 file outside of PS command line

Comment: Are you running powershell as an administrator when executing the script with it?

Comment: You need to declare the $source_businesspath variable before using it. Also there is a white space in between the first " and C.

Comment: i did declare before and still having the same problem

Comment: From your above code, you declared the variable ***after*** using it, and don't assure the path does exist/create it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've fixed the many quoting and logic problems here.

```
$source_businesspath = "work\test\$(Get-Date -Format 'yyyy-MM-dd')\business"

mkdir $source_businesspath

$newFILEStest=(1..10) 
foreach($f in $newFILEStest) 
{
  $newFiletest1="business" +$f + ".txt" 
  new-item -name $newfiletest1 -path $source_businesspath
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, i get the following error at new-item $newfiletest1 -path $source_businesspath – error: A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument ' business1.txt –

Comment: New-Item -Path $source_businesspath -Name $newFiletest1 -ItemType File    that solved my previous error

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure that your destination path exists before you create items in it. A simple Test-Path will be able to validate that the directory exists.

Obviously, you also need to have permission to create the directory and files.

```
$source_businesspath = "C:\Work\Test\$(Get-Date -Format 'yyyy-MM-dd')\business"
if (-not (Test-Path -Path $source_businesspath)) {
    New-Item -Path $source_businesspath -ItemType Directory -Force
}

$newFILEStest = (1..10) 
foreach ($f in $newFILEStest) {
    $newFiletest1 = "business" + $f + ".txt" 
    New-Item -Path $source_businesspath -Name $newfiletest1
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, i get the following error at  new-item $newfiletest1 -path $source_businesspath

Comment: error: A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument ' business1.txt

Comment: New-Item -Path $source_businesspath -Name $newFiletest1 -ItemType File    FIXED